# How I do I remove the User menu from the top right corner?

Tags: routes

How would I go about removing the "User menu" from being displayed in the top right corner of the site when logged in? It is set to display "None" in the block, yet it seems to be up there by default.

Other than using CSS to hide it, what is the recommended way to remove these links? I've got the login/logout links in my footer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In admin/structure/menu/settings, you select which is the source for the Main links, and the Secondary links.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

By default, the source for the Secondary links is the User menu; if you set it to *No Secondary links*, or another menu, the user links will disappear from the page.

Comment: Thank you! Worked, of course :)
I would like a Utility menu in between the Site logo and the search box, in the header of every page. Should I perhaps include it this way? As a secondary Links menu? Or should I include it via the template, or just blocks?